# Which are the deterministic sorting algorithms with O(nlogn)?

Tags: sorting, deterministic

> Which are the deterministic sorting algorithms with O(nlogn)...? Only
>   name few algorithms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge sort and heap sort are the archetypal `O(nlogn)` examples and are deterministic. Quicksort is `O(nlogn)` in the average case but not usually in the worst case (which is `O(n^2)`). Quicksort is very often implemented with a randomized pivot, so it's not always deterministic.